# Translation ready code format for taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, translation, textdomain

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

i have these doubts

- `_x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' )` does it make `taxonomy general name` a text domain? wont it resulting in multiple translation?
- `__( 'All Categories' ),__( 'Edit Category' )`etc does not seems to have any text domain, is it required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `_x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' )` does it make `taxonomy
>   general name` a text domain? wont it resulting in multiple
>   translation?

That `taxonomy general name` is the *[gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) or translation context* used in the POT file. The text domain is the [*third* parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/), which defaults to `default`.

- From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers):

  > Sometimes a single term is used in several contexts. Although it is
  >   one and the same word in English, it may need to be translated
  >   differently in some languages. For example, the word "Post" can be
  >   used both as a verb ("Click here to post your comment") and as a noun
  >   ("Edit this post"). In such cases, the `_x()` function should be used.
  >   It is similar to `__()`, but it has an additional second argument --
  >   the context:
  >
  > ```
  > if ( false === $commenttxt ) $commenttxt = _x( 'Comment', 'noun', 'my-text-domain' );
  > if ( false === $trackbacktxt ) $trackbacktxt = __( 'Trackback', 'my-text-domain' );
  > if ( false === $pingbacktxt ) $pingbacktxt = __( 'Pingback', 'my-text-domain' );
  > ...
  > // some other place in the code
  > echo _x( 'Comment', 'column name', 'my-text-domain' );
  > ```

"*wont it resulting in multiple translation?*" — yes, it would. But that's why the [`_x()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) has the context parameter. It helps you (as the developer) in retrieving the proper translation based on the context. (The context must *always* be specified when calling `_x()`.)

---

> `__( 'All Categories' ),__( 'Edit Category' )` etc does not seems to
>   have any text domain, is it required?

Just like the `_x()` function, when calling [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/), [`_e()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/), etc. without specifying a text domain, the text domain defaults to `default`; therefore:

- `__( 'All Categories' )` is equivalent to `__( 'All Categories', 'default' )`
- `__( 'Edit Category' )` is equivalent to `__( 'Edit Category', 'default' )`

I.e. The text domain is optional, in terms of the `__()` usage.

If you want your plugin/theme to be translatable (i.e. localized/internationalized), then yes, your plugin/theme should have a text domain, and always use it when using `__()`, `_e()`, or the other translation/gettext functions in WordPress.

---

Hope that helps, and for an in-depth guide on internationalization and localization in WordPress, check out the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). =)

---

### UPDATE

Here's a, hopefully :), more precise explanation regarding the `default` text domain:

1. When WordPress loads, it will load the MO (`.mo`) files for the default text domain which has `default` as its *unique identifier*. The MO files are by default stored in `wp-content/languages`; so if your site's language is Italiano, one of the MO files loaded into the text domain `default` is `wp-content/languages/it_IT.mo`.
2. When for example, you call the `__()` function **without** specifying a text domain, or by using the text domain `default`, like so:

   ```
   __( 'All Categories' )
   __( 'All Categories', 'default' )
   ```

   then WordPress will use the *translation entries* parsed from the `default`'s MO files (e.g. `wp-content/languages/it_IT.mo`) and lookup the translation of the text in those translation entries.

So if you want WordPress to lookup in the translation entries parsed from the MO file(s) of a theme or plugin, make sure to specify the correct text domain, like so:

```
__( 'All Categories', 'my-theme' )
__( 'All Categories', 'my-plugin' )
```

Because omitting the text domain (or setting it to `default`) does *not* make WordPress automatically lookup in the theme's/plugin's translation entries, and that the *same text* could exist in the translation entries of another text domain.

Comment: thank you :), just a thought, if the text domain defaults to `default`, is it okay to  omit my my text domain that i specified in the theme style? just to make the code typing easier ?

Comment: You're welcome @LatheeshVMVilla :) Sorry for the late reply. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I'm glad the update helped you :). But I updated it and hopefully it's more helpful than before. ;)